# Ubuntu 16.04.1 screen not turning off, screensaver not activating

Tags: monitor, screensaver

Since installing caffeine my screen is no longer turning off. I installed a screen saver, and that isn't working either. Caffeine wasn't running. I unistalled caffeine, but still no luck. Any suggestions as to how making my screen turn off again? It's set at 3 minutes. I disabled lock.
Thank you!

Comment: Did you just remove it or purge it?

Comment: I uninstalled it from the software manager

Comment: Try purging it using apt

Comment: appaently it was purged, because apt didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it deleted necessary package:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver
```

Should enable the screensaver:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled true
```

Time  in Second before the display darkens.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay "time/s"
```

Maybe the dim option is disbled:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim true
```

If you do not have display power management installed, then X-Server takes over this task.

```
xset +dpms && xset s on         -> Enabel DPMS and Screensaver
xset +dpms dpms 600 1200 1800   -> Standby, Suspend and Off set in seconds
```

Comment: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled true didn't work, neither did this: gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim true but this works: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay "time/s" Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: must be caffeine, when I reinstalled it I had the same problem. Is there an alternative to caffeine? I want the screen to stay on when watching a movie.

Comment: The screensaver I had installed was mate, not gnome. Gnome screensaver isn't in the ubuntu software. Anyway, I removed it, since it isn't working anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but that's above my head. I don't know if I have power management installed, if it doesn't come by default I guess not. I don't know what x-server does, but I only want suspend when I close the lid (i made that change in power settings).  I'll just forget about the screensaver, and will set the screen of time to never whenever I watch a movie. This was a lot easier in windows :-) Bit strange that ubuntu doesn't notice when watching movie in full screen.